# AWS SNS with FMC for SMS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am developing a React native application where I want to sent an SMS for OTP. I used AWS SNS for publishing messages after subscribing them to a topic, but I found that the price is quite high since the SMS is transactional.

I wanted to use Firebase Messaging Cloud since they do it for free but I don't really know how to proceed with it. Do I have to `createPlatformApplication` and then do `createPlatformEndpoint` for every user to send messages? This is a bit confusing for me, so if someone could give me an overview of the initial processes, it would do me wonders.

This is how I am doing it now simply using subscribe and publish:

[image: This is how I am doing it now simply using subscribe and publish]

Comment: It is easier to reproduce your setup if you paste your code instead of making a screenshot. Here is a post on how you can do that https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

I understood your question as asking how you could deliver OTP codes using push notifications.

To do that, you would:

1. Set up a platform application through SNS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-register.html
2. Create an endpoint for each end device you want to send these notifications to: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-platform-endpoint.html
3. Do a direct publish to that endpoint to send the notification only to that person: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-directmobile.html

For this use case, you do not need to use topics and subscriptions, since all of your messages will only be targeting one person.